# My python request proxy password has hashtag "#", it failed to parse the proxy URL

Tags: python, url, python-requests

my proxies is:  'http://abc:zyx#123$@http://proxy.mycompany.com:8800/';

when I run:

```
response = requests.get(
            url, stream=True, headers=headers, proxies=my_proxies);
```

I got the error:

File "C:\Program Files\Python\310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115, in post
return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python\310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python\310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python\310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python\310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 456, in send
raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: http://abc:zyx#123$@http://proxy.mycompany.com:8800/

when I remove # from password, I got the following error:  File "C:\Program Files\Python\310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115, in post
return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python\310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python\310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python\310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python\310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 513, in send
raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.precisely.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /oauth/token (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000202D2877190>: Failed to resolve 'http' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")))
Press any key to continue . . .

I believe the # in the password caused the error, how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1) the `userinfo` part needs to be pct-encoded:

> `userinfo    = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" )`

This should work:

```
my_proxies = {"http": "http://abc:zyx%23123%24@proxy.mycompany.com:8800/"}

response = requests.get(url, proxies=my_proxies)
```

Because the percent-encoded forms of [`#` and `$` are `%23` and `%24`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding#Reserved_characters), respectively.

Comment: I updated to requests-2.31.0, urllib3-2.0.4.  I used my_proxies = {"http": "http://abc:zyx%23123%24@proxy.mycompany.com:8800/"}; and I still get parse error: requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: zyx#123$@proxy.mycompany.com:8800/

Comment: it works when I run it in command line with %23 for # and %24 for $. The error I had is IDE error. Thank you @selcuk!